# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, graphics, camera, media, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting an error on the following line of code:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg");
```

The error is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

But the image is present in the directory

My USB connection is Charge only

Comment: "My USB connection is Charge only" - What sort of device is this? I seem to remember some issue on a particular device (can't remember which one) where 'Charge only' would cause problems with SD card access (even though it shouldn't have). I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never hardcode paths like `/sdcard`. For example, `/sdcard` is wrong on most Android devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to find the root of external storage.

Comment: now i am using this code -> FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalFileStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg");  still it is giving me the same error and then if i connect the phone with "Disk Drive" then i see the image and in properties i see some other path -> /media/NEW/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg  and if i hardcode this path also i still get the same error

Comment: You can also check if directories exist an files before accessing them:)

Comment: ya.. and you should read the post carefully before commenting

Comment: @abhishek: The proper way to construct `File` paths on Java is to use a `File` constructor, not concatenation. The path on your Linux PC ("in properties i see some other path -> /media/NEW/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg") has little to do with the path on your device. Make sure the device does not have USB mass storage enabled (which I assume is covered by your "My USB connection is Charge only" statement). Make sure you have your case correct (e.g., capital ROBIN).

Comment: ok so what should i write instead of this Environment.getExternalFileStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg"  since you prefer not to concat and my connection is charge only and the image path is also correct , i got it the linux pc path is not the correct one . File has read only permission

Comment: i am using getExternalFileStorageDirectory()

Comment: @abhishek: `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg")`

Comment: I think concatenating doesn't matter in this question.

Comment: File isfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/DCIM/ROBIN.jpg"); this doesnt gives any error but the following line gives again the same error FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(isfile); i have to do multipart data and upload it on server

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest.